# How to specify a parameter that can be undefined in flowjs

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I'm new to flowjs and do not yet understand how the typical use case of an undefined parameter should be modeled in flowjs.

```
function msg(message: string, callback: ?Function) {
   // ...
   if (_.isFunction(callback)) {
      callback();
   }
}
```

When checking the above function with flow, the following error message is shown:

- Function cannot be called on possibly null value function call.
- Function cannot be called on possibly undefined value

I do understand why the errors are shown but I'm not sure how to tell flowjs that this is intentional because the callback is only invoked when the parameter is not null or undefined?

Comment: Hrm looks like that should work, not sure what's up. Maybe try a more specific `if (typeof callback === 'function') {`. Also, make sure you really don't have any code in place of `// ...` in order to isolate the issue better. Also, an actual flow error printout could be helpful.

Comment: Knowing that this should actually work already helps. My example was (as always) to generic and in my actual production code, I typically do the null checking in a more explicit way, like if (_.isFunction(callback))

Comment: Well, that explains it. Flow does not know that `_.isFunction(callback)` returns `true` only if `callback` is a function. All it knows is that it returns a boolean (if you have the interface file for underscore/lodash set up). You should do native JS checks, then Flow can *refine* the type of callback from `?Function` to `Function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flow does not know that `_.isFunction(callback)` returns `true` only if `callback` is a function. All it knows is that it returns a boolean (if you have the interface file for underscore/lodash set up). You should do native JS checks instead, then Flow can refine the type of `callback` from `?Function` to `Function`. Like this: `if (typeof callback === 'function') { callback() }`.

A simpler type check should work as well: `if (callback) { callback() }` because Flow knows that if `callback` is not falsey, it has to be a function.

See more at https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html